# Angular Retrieve state of a component when navigating to another route that uses the same component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two different routes `/a` and `/b` using the same component. When navigating from `/a` to `/b`, I'd like to be able to retrieve the state of the component instance used in `/a` to reuse it in `/b`.

I read here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12446 that it is or will be possible using Angular "custom route reuse strategies". I am wondering if it's possible using the current [RouteReuseStrategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouteReuseStrategy-class.html)?
Because it seems to be easy to reuse a component when going back to the same url but not when going to a different url using the same component.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your real time use case but you can use RouteReuseStrategy reuse the UI or Component state. You have to generate a common unique key for both route and store that state when you leave the route. Stored state can be re-used when route back with routes which has same key.

> In this https://plnkr.co/edit/wFPn16?p=preview
>
> ```
>  Visited component state reused when you visit to different route.   For example view and edit item with id 12345. then check the view and> edit details for  id 12346.  View and edit component show the details related 12345.
> ```

HTH